# Given matrices $B$ and $C$. What is the value of $L$ that minimizes the value $||L^T \times B \times L - C||_F$?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Where $L \in R^{m \times n}$ and $B \in R^{m \times m}$ and $C \in R^{n \times n}$

$B$ and $C$ are symmetric positive semi-definite.

Where $\times$ denotes matrix multiplication and $||.||_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Does $\times$ just denote matrix multiplication?  And does $\|\cdot\|_F$ denote the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $U$ be an *orthogonal matrix* such that
$$
U^TCU = \pmatrix{\pmatrix{\sigma_1\\&\ddots\\&&\sigma_r}&0\\0&0}:= D
\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}
$$
where $r$ is the rank of $C$. Then by the unitary invariance of the Frobenius norm, we have
$$
\|L^TBL - C\|_F = \|(LU)^TB(LU) - D\|_F
$$

---

Steps towards finding a suitable $L$:

**Step 1:** Find an orthogonal $U$ that does what is described above.  We now define $L_1 = LU$ so that $L = L_1U^T$, and note that $L_1$ must minimize $\|L_1^TBL_1 - D\|_F$. We now consider 3 cases.

---

## Case 1: $m=n$

By Sylvester's law of inertia, we can find an invertible (square) $P$ such that
$$
P^TBP = \pmatrix{I_r & 0\\0 & 0} := E
$$
where $r = \rank(B)$. Let $L_2 = PL_1$, so that $L_1 = P^{-1}L_2$.  We now want $L_2$ that minimizes
$$
\|L_2^T E L_2 - D\|_F
$$
Now, set $L_2 = \sqrt{D}$.  So, all together, we now have 
$$
L = P^{-1}\sqrt{D}U^T
$$

Comment: Following your answer, I can see that if $L$ is orthogonal. Then, $(LU)^T B (LU) = \Sigma$ where $\Sigma$ is the singular values of $B$. However, this is not necessary the optimal choice of $L$ as the $B$ is given not chosen, and does not necessary has singular values close to those of $D$.

Comment: You don't need to make $L$ orthogonal.  The real point of my hint is that you can now focus on the problem of minimizing
$$
\|L^TBL - D\|_F
$$
and then use this result to get a general solution.

Comment: You might want to use [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).  The answer will depend on how the ranks of $B$ and $D$ (that is, $C$) compare.

Comment: If rank$(B) \geq $ rank$(C)$, then the minimum will be zero.  Otherwise, the minimum will be the sum of the rank$(C) - $ rank$(B)$ smallest singular values of $C$.

Comment: I am not sure if Sylvester's law of inertia can be used in this case, as it requires the matrix $L$ to be invertible which in my case is not square $\in R^{m \times n}$.

Comment: You can use it, but there's a bit of a *trick* to it. In particular, you can think of an $m \times n$ matrix as a block matrix that has a square matrix in it.

Comment: Note that:
$$
\pmatrix{L_0\\0}^T B \pmatrix{L_0\\0} = L_0^TBL_0\\
\pmatrix{L_0&0}^T B \pmatrix{L_0&0} = 
\pmatrix{ L_0^TBL_0 & 0\\0 & 0}
$$

Comment: I am not sure that I am following.  Sylvester's law of inertia is used to count the number of negative and positive elements of $D$ using the matrix B. How this can be useful for calculating the optimal $L$

Comment: Solved in the square case

Comment: Your edit was incorrect

Comment: If $$L_1 = P^{-1} L_2$$ then $$||L_1^T B L_1||_F = ||(P^{-1} L_2)^T B P^{-1} L_2||_F = ||L_2^T P^{-T} B P^{-1}L_2||_F$$. Which will only equal $$||L_2^TE L_2||_F$$ if $$P^{-T} B P^{-1} = E$$.